# Create table joining two existing tables in Shark Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, apache-spark, shark-sql

I have two tables `oldTable` and `newTable` with the contents as :

`oldTable` :

```
  key    value    volume
  ======================
  1      abc      10000
  2      def      5000
```

`newTable` :

```
  key    value    volume
  ======================
  1      abc      2000
  2      def      3000
  3      xyz      7000
```

I want to create a new table which sums up the `volume`s from bothe tables. i.e., the new table should contain the following contents :

`joined_table` :

```
  key    value    volume
  ======================
  1      abc      12000
  2      def      8000
  3      xyz      7000
```

I tried with the following statements but to no result :

```
CREATE TABLE joined_table AS
SELECT key, value, volume
FROM (
    SELECT IF(oldTable.key != NULL, oldTable.key, newTable.key) AS key,
        IF(oldTable.value != NULL, oldTable.value, newTable.value) AS value,
        IF(oldTable.volume AND newTable.volume, oldTable.volume + newTable.volume,
    IF(oldTable.volume != NULL, oldTable.volume, newTable.volume)) AS volume
    FROM(
        SELECT oldTable.key, oldTable.value, oldTable.volume, newTable.key, newTable.value, newTable.volume
        FROM newTable FULL OUTER JOIN oldTable ON newTable.key = oldTable.key
    )alias
)anotherAlias;
```

But this throws me an error saying `Query returned non-zero code: 10, cause: FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: Ambiguous column reference key`.

I tried changing the column names in the `joined_table` in the above query, but it gives me the same error. Any help on how to achieve this ?

Also, is there any way I can overwrite the result to an existing table, say `oldTable` instead of creating this new one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I managed to get this done using the following :

```
CREATE TABLE joined_table AS SELECT 
IF (newTable.key IS NULL, oldTable.key, newTable.key) as key, 
IF (newTable.value IS NULL, oldTable.value, newTable.value) as value, 
IF(newTable.volume IS NULL, oldTable.volume, 
   IF(oldTable.volume IS NULL, newTable.volume, oldTable.volume + newTable.volume)) as volume 
FROM newTable FULL OUTER JOIN oldTable ON newTable.key = oldTable.key;
```

I still have to figure out how to update the existing table without creating a new one.

**UPDATE**

`INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE oldTable SELECT` ... does the updation to the existing table.

Answer (score 0):

The word `key` that you are using in your query is a reserved keyword. This might be the reason of ambiguity error being thrown by your parser. You can use back ticks to avoid the parser to read it as a reserved literal.

```
CREATE TABLE joined_table AS
SELECT `key`, value, volume
FROM (
SELECT IF(oldTable.`key` != NULL, oldTable.`key`, newTable.`key`) AS `key`,
    IF(oldTable.value != NULL, oldTable.value, newTable.value) AS value,
    IF(oldTable.volume AND newTable.volume, oldTable.volume + newTable.volume,
IF(oldTable.volume != NULL, oldTable.volume, newTable.volume)) AS volume
FROM(
    SELECT oldTable.`key`, oldTable.value, oldTable.volume, newTable.`key`, newTable.value, newTable,volume
    FROM newTable FULL OUTER JOIN oldTable ON newTable.`key` = oldTable.`key`;
)alias
)anotherAlias;
```

Comment: No. This doesn't change anything. Moreover, I can do joins using 'key' without backticks and that works, e.g., SELECT oldTable.key, oldTable.value, oldTable.volume, newTable.key, newTable.value, newTable.volume FROM newTable FULL OUTER JOIN oldTable ON newTable.key = oldTable.key;